# Binding dynamically created table entries with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 to dynamically generate rows in a table. I want to use Knockout to bind the enabled property of a checkbox in each generated row of said table to an expression that is evaluating whether or not there are a given number of checked boxes in that column.

Here's an example of my table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Happy?</th>
    </tr>
    @for (int z = 0; z < Model.People.Count; z++) { 
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.CheckboxFor(Model.People[z].Happy,new{@data_bind= "checked: CheckedHappyPeople, enable: CheckedHappyPeople.length < 5 || CheckedHappyPeople"})
        </td>
    }
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my VM:

```
function viewModel(){
var self = this;
self.CheckedHappyPeople = ko.observableArray();
}
```

And my model:

```
public class PeopleViewModel
{
public List<People> {get; set;}

public PeopleViewModel(){}
}

public class People
{
public bool Happy {get; set;}
}
```

With what I have above, whenever I select a "happy" checkbox, all checkboxes in the table get checked/unchecked. How can I use Knockout to bind to these dynamically generated elements? Should I use the `foreach` binding within ASP.NET MVC4 somehow?

Comment: Is the table dynamically generated using (client side) KO's `foreach`, or is generated in the server?

Comment: His code is shown there, but what is disappointing is that you haven't actually tried anything, you are just asking other people to write code for you.  Definitely not a good way to learn.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos The table is being generated dynamically server-side without use of KO's `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

You should really try to learn and understand Knockout instead of asking others to write code for you.  For one, you aren't learning anything by having someone else do it for you, and two, you don't understand the code that I am writing for you.  That being said, this is a solution that others may be looking for in the future so here is the answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/gzsgy/14/

```
<input data-bind="checked: Selected, enable: $parent.selections() < 5 || Selected()" type="checkbox" />
```

Keep track of the selections and then disable the checkbox if there are 5 or more selections or it is already checked, so that you can still uncheck it.

Comment: I kept my example basic, but based on your feedback I've revised my question and included more code. Your solution didn't touch on the crux of my problem: dynamically generated elements (you created multiple entities by hand in your VM). With the new information I've provided maybe you can help me understand how to bind to dynamically generated elements, through the `foreach` binding or some kind of templating. Regardless, thanks for the help.

Comment: If you knew knockout that answer does show you.  You need to subscribe to each newly created objects selected property, just like I do with the ko.utils.arrayForEach